# Why plugin protobuf does not generate classes in the target folder?

Tags: java, maven, grpc, rpc, grpc-java

I just started to study jrpc.I created a simple proto file in the proto package.

```
syntax = "proto3";

service HelloWorldService {
  rpc hello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
  string text = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
  string text = 1;
}
```

I use maven.In the pom.xml file I have dependencies like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>grpc-hello-server</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>GRPC</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.48.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.48.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.48.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.24.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then i click reload all maven projects button and then in maven lifecycle i click package run. And if i understand correctly my protobuf plugin must created classes in target/generated-sources folder. But it's empty. I don't understand why, i cleaned maven, installed and then again used package command.And that didn't help.Please tell me why my files are not being created?

Comment: `I created a simple proto file in the proto package` - what does it mean? `protobuf-maven-plugin` expects to find `proto` files in `src/main/proto`

Comment: You're right. Due to inattention, I threw a package of proto src/main/java/proto . And that's why it didn't generate files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Proto files should be stored at src/main/proto